# In postgres, Getting an error database connection failed: FATAL: cache lookup failed for access method 403,

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

While opening the connection in pgAdmin, I am unable to connect to a certain database:

```
FATAL: cache lookup failed for access method 203 
ERROR: relation "metadata" does not exist at character 120.
```

But in same server, I am able to connect to other database.

Please help on it.

I tried to restart the server but it is not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If access method 403 (B-tree) has vanished from your system catalogs, the database is probably broken beyond repair. Restore your backup.

The alternative is to hire a PostgreSQL expert who can salvage some of the data. This will be expensive, and success is not guaranteed. Don't try to do that yourself (if you ask such a question).